# PHPUnit not providing enough information on skipped and incomplete tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to capture the output of PHPUnit:

```
$pu_result = new \PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult();
$pu_result->addListener(new \PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON());      

$pu_suite = new \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite();

// here I add tests  
// $pu_suite->addTestSuite(...);

ob_start();
$pu_suite->run($pu_result);    
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

this gives me a json encoded string as $output (bad json btw, but I can fix it).

The problem is that the "message" property for incomplete and skipped tests is "Skipped test" or "Incomplete Test" and doesn't contain the message I provided in the `$this->markTestIncomplete()` or `$this->markTestSkipped()` calls :(

Can I get that too?

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example we could play with? (Also showing the output you get, and the output you expect, would be great.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get these in the JSON log by upgrading to the latest 3.6 release. Looking at the [latest `PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON` source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/Util/Log/JSON.php#L123) for `addIncompleteTest` and `addSkippedTest`, I can see that they both add the exception message in the log. I cannot, however, find *when* this change was made. If those changes aren't in 3.6.x, you can create your own subclass and override those methods very easily.

Comment: tx. it doesn't appear that the updated class is included in the standard release though..

Comment: You're correct. Those changes don't appear in the 3.6 branch--only `master`.

Answer (score 7):

Try to run phpunit with -v option (--verbose)

Answer (score 1):

Watchout for defining a `printerClass` setting in either the phpunit.xml or whatever else configuration. The default printer class will include skipped tests but others may not.

`"PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"` for example, does not print any skipped tests.